# Android (Java) convert JSONArray to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have a JSONObject:

```
try {
    JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject("{ \"options\": [\"Oui\", \"Non\"] }");
    JSONArray myJsonArray = myJsonObject.getJSONArray("options");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

myJsonArray.toString() contain:

```
["Yes", "No"]
```

I need to convert it to a JSONObject like this:

```
{ "0": "Yes", "1": "No" }
```

and also to:

```
{ "Yes": "Yes", "No": "No" }
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Did you try something?? If not please try to do on your own first. Its not something very difficult. Just about the loop and creation of object for each item of array

Comment: I'm so stupid, of course : for(int i = 0; i < myJsonArray.length(); i++){ String a = myJsonArray.getString(i); }

Answer (score 1):

Of course the answer is :

```
JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject("{ \"options\": [\"Oui\", \"Non\"] }");
JSONArray myJsonArray = myJsonObject.getJSONArray("options");

JSONObject myJsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
for(int i = 0; i < myJsonArray.length(); i++){
    String a = myJsonArray.getString(i);
    myJsonObject2.put(a, a);
}
```

Sorry, I got confused.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method [toJSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#toJSONObject(org.json.JSONArray)) for creating new JSONObjects from a JSONArray.
Try this:

```
try {
    JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject("{ \"options\": [\"Oui\", \"Non\"] }");
    JSONArray myJsonArray = myJsonObject.getJSONArray("options");

    // creates a new JSON Object with the given keys
    JSONObject result = myJsonArray.toJSONObject(myJsonArray);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```